# Cannot create form field as model is not loaded

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Here is my model

```
class AbstractSubnet(TimeStampedEditableModel):
    subnet = NetworkField(default="10.0.0.0/24")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    master_subnet = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                      blank=True, null=True,
                                      related_name="child_subnets")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.subnet)
```

And the form:

```
class AbstractSubnetAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AbstractSubnet
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is giving me the following error, and I guess it's quite obvious as well,

`ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'master_subnet' yet, because its related model 'django_ipam.Subnet' has not been loaded yet`

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: why are you using the abstract model in the AdminForm? Shouldn't it be `model = Subnet`?

Comment: Do `exclude = ['master_subnet']` instead of `fields='__all__`'. If you want to edit the master_subnet field as well, you can add it in dynamically when a pk for that model exists